# How to Connect Ncreport with MS Access database

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to this. I want to use ncreport with my qt project to generate reports as crystal reports are not compatible with it. I am using MS Access database. I want to connect it with my ncreport. Can anyone guide me Where I can get the hostname/IP address for the QODBC connection? or how I can connect my database with the ncreport?

Help will be appreciated.
Thanks